# Lazy collection initialization fails in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, lazy-initialization

Today I faced with next problem in hibernate:

My method:

```
@Transactional
public Period getDefault(Team team) {
    Period defaultPeriod = team.getDefaultPeriod();
    List<Period> periods = _periodDAO.getPeriods(team);
        if (!periods.contains(defaultPeriod)) {
            defaultPeriod = periods.get(periods.size() - 1);
        }
    }
    _periodDAO.initializeIssues(defaultPeriod);
    return defaultPeriod;
}
```

Method initializeIssues:

```
public void initializeIssues(Period period) {
    if (period.getIssues() != null) {
        Hibernate.initialize(period.getIssues());
    }
}
```

I receive exception if collection **periods** contains **defaultPeriod**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: collection is not associated with any session
at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:474)
at org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:417)
```

But if I remove some lines and change method to

```
@Transactional    
public Period getDefault(Team team) {
    Period defaultPeriod = team.getDefaultPeriod();
    _periodDAO.initializeIssues(defaultPeriod);
    return defaultPeriod;
}
```

It works fine.

I debugged first example and hibernate session does not close during whole method.

As I understand, if loaded object (one element in **periods**) in session  has collection which associated with active session and existing before object (**defaultPeriod**) also has same association - it (**defaultPeriod**) will lose its association.

Is it truth? Who else faced with same problem?

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 13):

Presumably, your `Team` argument is coming from another transaction and another Hibernate `Session`.

When a `@Transactional` method returns, the `TransactionManager` closes the `Session` which does some cleanup and unsets (sets to `null`) the `Session` field of all `PersistentCollection` instances. Your `defaultPeriod` has one of these in its `issues` field.

Hibernate's `Hibernate.initialize()` forces the initialization of a lazy `PersistentCollection`, but has the following code (calls `AbstractPersistentCollection#forceInitialization()`)

```
    if ( session == null ) {
        throw new HibernateException( "collection is not associated with any session" );
    }
```

If you are planning on using the `issues` collection outside the original `@Transactional` method (the code that produces `Team`), you need to load the underlying objects. Either change it to EAGER loading or do what you are doing with `Hibernate.initialize()`.

Another solution is to make the `Session` last longer than just the length of the first `@Transactional`, but I don't have details for that. A quick google or SO search should bring up some options.

---

This is what is happening

```
Period defaultPeriod = team.getDefaultPeriod();
```

gets a `Period` object with id (ex.) `42`. Because it happened in another `Session` that has since been closed, the `issues` is a `PersistentCollection` which has a `null` `Session` reference, and will throw the `Exception` you get.

The you do this

```
List<Period> periods = _periodDAO.getPeriods(team);
```

Let's say the `List` contains a `Period` object with id `42`, so the `if` in

```
   if (!periods.contains(defaultPeriod)) {
        defaultPeriod = periods.get(periods.size() - 1);
   }
```

doesn't get executed. Although the `equals()` returns `true` (`contains()` also returns `true` and becomes `false` because of `!`), the objects are not the same. The on in the `List` has an attached (non-null) `Session`, so that one can be initialized. But yours, the one held by `defaultPeriod` cannot.

Comment: Thank you!  But **TransactionManager** sets to null the **Session** field for *issues* in *defaultPeriod* only if *periods* contains *defaultPeriod*, if not - *issues* will initialize well.

Comment: @OleksandrZ I would take a look at your `equals()` method for comparing instances of `Period`. Although `Periods` might contain it, the one in the collection is attached to a `Session`, while the one on the outside is not.

Comment: **equals** method is very simple and based on comparing of **Period** id. I can initialize issues of **defaultPeriod** only if I don't retreive from db this entity again, so if I change code and add **Period defaultPeriod2 = _periodDAO.get(defaultPeriod.getId());** instead of retrieving **periods**, issues will be not initialized again. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I missed **@Transactional** for another method **getDefault** in my question where I don't use **_periodDAO**. Sorry. So, as I understand, new transaction will be created only if I use query to db, not initialize existing collection.

Comment: Whatever happens inside a `@Transactional` will happen within a Hibernate `Session`, within a  `Transaction`. When that method returns, depending on config, the `Transaction` will be committed and the `Session` will be closed. Initializing the collection can only happen if the `Session` is not closed yet. I don't think it necessarily has to be within the same `Transaction`.